# Getting status of FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using this code to get an `ExecutorService` in java:

`this.exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

Now I would like to know how many jobs it has processed, how many are in the queue (most importantly!), and basically all the information I could get. But an ordinary `ExecutorService` does not have this information. But according to [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265869/elegantly-implementing-queue-length-indicators-to-executorservices/2266421#comment18986560_2266421), I could typecast it to `ThreadPoolExecutor` because that's what it returns. Well, that sounds easy... but there's one problem. **My machine does not return `ThreadPoolExecutor`!**

Instead I am given a `java.util.concurrent.Executors$FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` which, when trying to typecast to that, is impossible because the class is not visible.

So how can I find out the status of my `ExecutorService`?

*If you are very curious and would like to know what I am using my `ExecutorService` for (if that matters), read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145588/java-single-worker-thread-for-sql-update-statements) that I have asked earlier. It's basically for SQL statements.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1

You can create your own ThreadPoolExecutor - this is what `newFixedThreadPool` does:

```
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

You can then keep a reference to the queue to see how full it is. You can even pass in a modified version which keeps a counter of number of jobs received.

Option 2

You could use [an `ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) which will help you know when a task completes - you can then count how many jobs you have submitted / how many have completed.